# How to define superclass?

Tags: class, haskell, instance

How does one define a super class in Haskell? My situation is that I have defined a class `StringHashed` that maps members to their names as a String. I wish to implement, en mass, all `t` from `Show t` by making the string name simply return `show t`. Am I right in saying that `StringHashed` is now a superclass of Show? Here is what I would like to be able to write:

```
class StringHashed t where
    stringHash :: t -> String

instance Show t => StringHashed t where
    stringHash = show
```

But Haskell complains about an invalid instance declaration. I have also tried `instance StringHashed (Show t)` and other syntactical dribble; none have worked for me. I have also read a proposal on the GHC wiki that provides no solution. [This is the one](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DefaultSuperclassInstances). I have concern about using `-XFlexibleInstances` simply because it is not default. Is there a proper way to achieve a general instance declaration? Or am I being too demanding of Haskell's type system?

Comment: Use `class (Show t) => StringHashed t where` for a superclass.  But I'm not sure the instance is really what you want.

Comment: And for implementations of non-`Show`s? I guess I can only ever build subclasses this way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Haskell superclasses cannot be added after the fact - they need to be mentioned in the subclass's declaration.  And defining an instance like you do in the question, while possible with extensions, can create subtle overlap problems.

`FlexibleInstances` itself is not the problem - it's one of GHC's most innocuous extensions. The problem is that GHC's instance lookup method means that

```
instance Show t => StringHashed t where ...
```

defines this instance to hold for *all* types `t` - the `Show t` restriction is only an afterthought checked after lookup.  So it will overlap with all other instances you can make, and while there is an extension `OverlappingInstances` to allow this, it is considered somewhat dubious to use.

However GHC has a feature `DefaultSignatures`, which is designed for use cases similar to yours:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

class StringHashed t where
    stringHash :: t -> String
    default stringHash :: Show t => t -> String
    stringHash = show

instance StringHashed Int
```

This allows you to write a default for the method which only works for some instance types.  Note however, that you still need to write an actual instance declaration for each type - but its body can be empty.

Comment: Yes, I thought it seemed a bit hopeful. Thanks for the good answer and the workarounds. I think I will stick to by-the-book Haskell - I will stay out of trouble that way.

Comment: @bimmo You should try whatever you think is reasonable, some of it probably works.  There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your original instance declaration,it's just not how Haskell currently works.